# Register -SPWorkFlowService gives 500 not found internal server error

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server, configuration, workflow-manager

I am trying to install and configure workflow manager since last many days but I am getting this 500.24 Internal server error or 500 not found error.

Workflow manager 1.0 refresh with cu2 installed perfectly but when trying to run the "Register-SPWorflowService" cmdlet to complete the installation, i get the following error : "An internal error occurred". I have attached the image.

The workflow backend service is started. Everything is fine except sharepoint 2013 is not able to find the workflow service.

And when i try to access the Workflow Management Site on port 12291, `HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error`
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Workflow manager is properly installed and I have done around 7 - 8 times new installation.

Sharepoint 2013 has SP1 installed on windows 2012 r2.

I am gone nuts. What could be the issue.

The log error says

```
> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InternalServerException: An internal error
> occured. For more details, please see the server logs. Client
> ActivityId : 349096cf-74bd-4f3f-a1df-6e9824fb80f9. --->
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)
> Internal Server Error.     at
> Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
> result)     at
> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
> result)     at
> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest
> request, T content)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
> at
> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest
> request, T content)     at
> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest
> request, T content)   ... 349096cf-74bd-4f3f-a1df-6e9824fb80f9
> 12/15/2014 10:24:33.80*   PowerShell.exe (0x2B88)                
>   0x4574  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell                   
>   6tf2    High        ...  at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ScopeManager.Get()   
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.RegisterFarm()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()  349096cf-74bd-4f3f-a1df-6e9824fb80f9
> 12/15/2014 10:24:33.80    PowerShell.exe (0x2B88)                
>   0x4574  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell                   
>   91ux    High        Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object 
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService
> Details  NULL  RecommendedAction
> NULL  349096cf-74bd-4f3f-a1df-6e9824fb80f9
```

Kindly help me with this

[image]

Comment: check this one hope fully help u http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67387/sharepoint-2013-workflow-configuration-error-authentication